# "Unindent does not match any outer indentation level" in Python

Tags: python, indentation

I have some Python code that does not run. The error message says:

> unindent does not match any outer indentation level

```
def main1():       

        password = "LPPJJAS"
        user_input = raw_input('Please Enter Password: ')

        if user_input == password:
                print 'All distances have been split so one pixel is equal to two centimetres'
               time.sleep(1)


        elif user_input != password:
                print 'Incorrect Password, terminating... \n'
                exit("pow")

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main1()`
```

Comment: The error message should give you a hint as to where, but to me it looks like an extra space before `print 'All distances...'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra space before line 5 - `print 'All distances...`. Python expects equal indents for every line. (Usually 4 spaces.)

```
password = "LPPJJAS"
user_input = raw_input('Please Enter Password: ')

if user_input == password:
    print 'All distances have been split so one pixel is equal to two centimetres'
    time.sleep(1)

elif user_input != password:
    print 'Incorrect Password, terminating... \n'
    exit("pow")
```

Comment: Apparently, the error is after `time.sleep(1)` as outer indentation not matching.